# Saving drag & dropped content to localStorage in html

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, local-storage

I would like the user of my webpage to drag and drop key-words from a text into a "notebook".
I would like the page to save the dropped elements.
What is the command for :

> The word Bob was dragged into the div "notebook" - "Bob" is thus stored into localStorage.

Analogously, dragging out of the "notebook" div would mean removing from localStorage.

I hope my very first stack overflow question is comprehensible.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: are you trying to achieve this ? - http://jsfiddle.net/bsvveen/mrjcpocs/ || https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384414/how-to-save-dragdrop-to-localstorage, check and let me know.

Comment: Thank you Lakshman, it indeed is, sorry I didn't find it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save drag&drop to localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384414/how-to-save-dragdrop-to-localstorage)

Comment: no problem @sannine